# swipe up in iOS

Tags: ios

I would like to develop a swipe up navigation just like,
   1) The camera button swipe up in the locked iPhone home screen
   2) the top-to-bottom page swipe which shows weather details in iPhone screen.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BauJ8.jpg

I tried different page gestures etc, but no luck.

Could anyone pls let me know the approach or any sample tutorial ?

Much Appreciated.

Thanks
Prakash

Comment: Have you tried using a 'touch' gesture, detecting whether the finger is in the 'target area', and then following the touch gesture on it's way down?

Comment: I thought of using touches moved, but couldn't implement desired output. Any samples or tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom View with Custom Gesture solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

With this gesture recognizer you can handle gesture direction and velocity. Here are some actions you may be interested in:

- (CGPoint)velocityInView:(UIView *)view
- (CGPoint)translationInView:(UIView *)view

Comment: UIPanGestureRecognizer seems to be not a best solution for page swipe up and down.